# WooCommerce: Call to a member function update_meta_data()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following code inside my WC Plugin:

```
$product = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $wproduct['code'] );
$product->update_meta_data('_bims_id', $wproduct['bims_id']);
$product->save();
```

But it throws the following exception:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
> update_meta_data() on int

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in which action or filter are you hooking this code?

Comment: You assigned the id of your product to `$product` variable. You could use this `update_post_meta( $product, '_bims_id', $wproduct['bims_id'] );`

Answer (score 0):

As Ruvee said,

I was getting the Product ID and not the Product Object by using **wc_get_product_id_by_sku**.

Adjusting to `update_post_meta( $product, '_bims_id', $wproduct['bims_id'] );` works pretty well.

Thank you !